# ViewState posted but sometimes missing on server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

Sometimes ViewState is posted to the server, but the server doesn't parse/use it so the page displays the page without the data from ViewState.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //fill data
        txtName.Text = "Some text";
    }
}
```

Sometimes the GET-request succeeds, but then the postback (button, linklabel etc.) doesn't serialize/deserialize the ViewState successfully. so the text-field is empty.

The data is in the hidden ViewState-input (right clicking and selecting refresh in browser, then clicking yes to post the same data) then it succeeds.

It's kind of random, works for a half hour, then 5 tries in a row fails. Can't find anything in the EventLog or IIS log.

It's a web farm environment, but the web servers have machineKey's, session etc. configured correctly. It's the latest publish with the 'old code' that just stopped working.

Any ideas on what's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing ViewState Encryption solved the problem.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
```